# JavaScript: Slide a UL down to last element

Tags: javascript

Can't think how best to do this. Thought it would be a simple show/hide but it dosn't seem as simple as that.

There is a UL with an indeterminable amount of items in it. It needs to be able to show the first 10 but no more unless a 'show more' button is clicked. When the 'show more' button is clicked it will expand the list open to show the complete list.

http://jsfiddle.net/kbUhW/

Interested to see how this is achieved.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WqxGf/

JS:

```
count = 0;
$('ul li').hide();
$('ul').children().each(function(){
    if(count >= 10) return;
    $(this).show();
    count++;
})

$('.slide').click(function(){$('ul li').show('blind');})
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
    <li>Item Five</li>
    <li>Item Six</li>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
    <li>Item Five</li>
    <li>Item Six</li>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
    <li>Item Five</li>
    <li>Item Six</li>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
    <li>Item Five</li>
    <li>Item Six</li>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
    <li>Item Five</li>
    <li>Item Six</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class='slide'>Slide Down</a>
```

Comment: lol which part of it? :-p mine is much more expandable (if you want to change any of the top 10 items in different ways :-P) its ok. i dont car ^_^

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers use jQuery, but your question didn't actually specify it. So here's one way to do it with plain JavaScript. Let's assume your `<ul>` has the ID `foo`, your "reveal" link has the ID `reveal`, and that there's a class `hide` with `display: none`. Then we have:

```
(function getChildNodes(id, num) { // ID of element, number to show
  var obj = document.getElementById(id),
    children = obj.childNodes,
    elemcounter = 0;   
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { // loop all children
    if (children[i].nodeType === 1) { // examine elements only
      elemcounter++;
      if (elemcounter > num) { // element number in range to hide?
        children[i].className = 'hide';
      }
    }
  }
}('foo', 3)); // id foo, show 3

document.getElementById('reveal').onclick = function() { // handle click
  var items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ){ // for all list elements...
    var tempclass = items[i].className;
    // if the class is "hide", unhide
    items[i].className = tempclass === 'hide' ? '' : tempclass;   
  }
}
```

Of course there are many other ways to do this more thoroughly -- and this one doesn't even slide. jQuery does make life a bit easier.

Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/jsQ47/

Answer (score 0):

Here's with the slide down effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/deNzh/

That's what you're looking for, right?

Answer (score 0):

you could assign the first ten < li >s a class like < li class="always_show">Stuff goes here< /li > and then make a script that hides all, shows the "always_show" class and waits for a button click to show the whole thing.

might look something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#listorama").hide();

});
$(function(){
    $(".always_show").show();

});
$(function(){
    $("#show_all").click(function(){
        $("#listorama").show();
    });

});
</script>

    <ul id="listorama">
        <li class="always_show"></li>    
        <li class="always_show"></li>  
        <li class="always_show"></li>  
        <li class="always_show"></li>  
        <li class="always_show"></li>  
        <li class="always_show"></li>  
        <li class="always_show"></li>  
        <li class="always_show"></li>  
        <li class="always_show"></li>  
        <li class="always_show"></li>  
        <li>stuff to hide first</li>
        <li>stuff to hide first</li>
        <li>stuff to hide first</li>
        <li>stuff to hide first</li>
        <li>stuff to hide first</li>
</ul>

<button id="show_all">Show All</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Andy

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleListDisplay (list, cap) {
    cap = parseInt(cap);
    if (cap == null || cap < 0) { return; }
    var elements = $(list).children();
    if ($(elements[cap]).css('display') == 'none') {
        // means we need to expand the list
        elements.each(function(ind, ele) {
            if (ind >= cap) { $(ele).slideDown(); }
        });
        $('.slide').html('Slide Up');
    } else {
        // means we need to shorten the list
        elements.each(function(ind, ele) {
            if (ind >= cap) { $(ele).slideUp(); }
        });
        $('.slide').html('Slide Down');
    }
}

$('.slide').click(function(){
        toggleListDisplay('#tester', 10);
})

toggleListDisplay('#tester', 10);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WqxGf/7/

Comment: Way more than what's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the others feel like making such a simple task more complicated than it is, but here is a much easier, shorter, and simpler way of achieving this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var ul = $("#myid");   
    ul.animate({"height": ul[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kbUhW/13/